# Etale map from a variety to an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, elliptic-curves

I read this sentence and I can't see why it is true.
Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over an algebraically closed field $k$, 
 $f\colon Y\to E$ an etale map; then $Y$ is also a curve over $k$.

Can someone explain me why? Is it only true for etale morphisms or also for a more generic class of morphisms?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not true. Perhaps they meant finite étale? You could do something like take an infinite disjoint union of $E$'s. Anyways, if $f$ is finite étale then $f$ is necessarily surjective (why?) and so you have a finite flat surjective map, which implies (with very little extra thought) that $\dim Y=\dim E$. So, $Y$ is dimension $1$. It's smooth because, without loss of generality, $k=\overline{k}$, and étale maps induce isomorphisms on completions of local rings. So, $Y$ is smooth of dimension $1$. It's projective because $E$ is, and $f$ is finite, and if $Y$ is connected

Comment: it's then a smooth projective integral (why?) curve. The Riemann-Hurwtiz formula then tells you it's genus $1$. Then, basic theory tells you you can gkve $Y$ the unique structure of a group such that this map is a morphism. So, without loss of generality $Y$ is an elliptic curve and $f:Y\to E$ is a group map. You can then dominate this map by $[m]:E\to E$, where $n=\deg f$ (which needs to be coprime to  char of $k$), so that this shows $\pi_1(E)$ is the prime-to-p Tate module of $E$.

Comment: It is not specified if the morphism is finite, but after your comment I think that, since for a quasi-separated scheme the etale site and the small etale site (defined by finitely presentated etale morphisms) are equivalent as categories, being $E$ a variety we can reduce to the case of finite presentation, and maybe we are done

Comment: This is not true. First and foremost, the small étale site is defined as having underlying category *all* étale morphisms $X\to Y$. In particular, an étale morphism is required only to be *locally* of finite presentation. Thus, the canonical map $\displaystyle \bigsqcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}E\to E$ is étale and certainly this left hand object is not a curve.

Comment: Ok, the example is clear, thank you... but about the etale site: I  found (in G. Tamme book) that the small etale site is defined with finitely presented etale morphism, while the big one with locally finitely presented etale morphism. Also Milne uses finite type morphism to define the small site and locally of finite type for the big one... so what is for you the small etale site?

Comment: For me, following, say, SGA, is that the étale site is just the site whose morphisms are just all étale morphisms $X\to Y$. This is also the definition take in Milne's book (perhaps not his notes, which are often times less precise). In particular, an étale morphism, for me, is any of the following:

1) Locally of finite presentation and formally étale.

2) Flat and unramified (i.e. locally of finite presentation and formally unramified, or, equivalently, locally of finite presentation and vanishing cotangent sheaf).

In either of these definitions, locally of finite presentation is all

Comment: that is needed. I don't think this is something to sweat over (it's a detail that I rarely pay attention to, unless I need to). This may be why Tamme just uses finitely presented, and Milne's notes (which are notoriously imprecise, compared to his text which is beautifully precise!) just ignores it all together.

Comment: I agree that this is not the core of the subject, I was just thinking about in order to solve the initial problem; but note: in Milne's book, pag 46-47, he declares that the class of morphism he wants to use is the one of finite type etale morphism, condition that is needed, I think, also to prove some results like theorem 2.17.

Comment: Huh, weird. To double check if I was crazy, I checked the Stacks Project. The definition of the Small Étale site is here (http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/021B) and their definition of étale is here (http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0259) and just restricts to the case of locally Noetherian schemes (for some reason), but in particular, only assumes locally of finite type. I feel like this is largely academic since these two categories are essentially the same (maybe they have the same topoi)? Anyways, if you assume actually finite presentation

Comment: then your $Y$ is still a smooth $1$-dimensional quasicompact shceme. The smoothness result I stated above did not use finite, and finite presentation+étale=quasi-finite which should give the $1$-dimensional result. Of course, you won't get any sort of projectivity result since you could take the map to be a Zariski open embedding.

Comment: PS, this is also the definition taken in Lei Fu (i.e. SGA translated into English :) )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36247/discussion-between-alex-youcis-and-user266704).

Comment: Dear @Alex, I think that particular Stacks chapter is meant to discuss étale morphisms and their structure in the simpler context with Noetherian hypotheses, but in the section in Morphisms of Schemes devoted to étale morphisms (or the section in Commutative Algebra on étale ring maps) there definitely are no Noetherian hypotheses, and in particular there are none in the Stacks definition of étale sites.